# Error when downloading cygwin packages from mirror sites in installation phase

Tags: cygwin

I'm having these two problems when trying to install cygwin :

1. When choosing "Direct Connection" or "Use Internet Explorer Settings" the installation wizard doesnt download any mirror site, even if those are accessible from my browser
2. When I add manually a site and select it to proceed I get the error in the second and third pictures

[image]

[image]
[image]

And here is the complete logs found under the cygwin install directory :

```
2017/02/14 12:12:17 Starting cygwin install, version 2.877
2017/02/14 12:12:17 User has backup/restore rights
2017/02/14 12:12:17 io_stream_cygfile: fopen(/etc/setup/setup.rc) failed 2 No such file or directory
2017/02/14 12:12:17 Current Directory: C:\Users\meee\Downloads
2017/02/14 12:12:17 Could not open service McShield for query, start and stop. McAfee may not be installed, or we don't have access.
2017/02/14 12:12:27 source: network install
2017/02/14 12:12:29 root: C:\cygwin system
2017/02/14 12:12:45 Selected local directory: C:\Users\meee\Downloads
2017/02/14 12:12:50 net: IE5
2017/02/14 12:14:21 site: http://mirrors.metapeer.com/cygwin/;mirrors.metapeer.com;United States;Washington/
2017/02/14 12:14:23 mbox note: Internal Error:  gcrypt library error 60 illegal tag.
2017/02/14 12:14:46 mbox note: Mirror Error:  Setup.ini signature http://mirrors.metapeer.com/cygwin/;mirrors.metapeer.com;United States;Washington/x86/setup.xz.sig from http://mirrors.metapeer.com/cygwin/;mirrors.metapeer.com;United States;Washington/ failed to verify.
Possible corrupt mirror?  Setup.ini rejected.
2017/02/14 12:14:48 mbox note: Internal Error:  gcrypt library error 60 illegal tag.
2017/02/14 12:14:49 mbox note: Mirror Error:  Setup.ini signature http://mirrors.metapeer.com/cygwin/;mirrors.metapeer.com;United States;Washington/x86/setup.bz2.sig from http://mirrors.metapeer.com/cygwin/;mirrors.metapeer.com;United States;Washington/ failed to verify.
Possible corrupt mirror?  Setup.ini rejected.
2017/02/14 12:14:50 mbox note: Internal Error:  gcrypt library error 60 illegal tag.
2017/02/14 12:14:51 mbox note: Mirror Error:  Setup.ini signature http://mirrors.metapeer.com/cygwin/;mirrors.metapeer.com;United States;Washington/x86/setup.ini.sig from http://mirrors.metapeer.com/cygwin/;mirrors.metapeer.com;United States;Washington/ failed to verify.
Possible corrupt mirror?  Setup.ini rejected.
2017/02/14 12:14:52 mbox note: Unable to get setup from <http://mirrors.metapeer.com/cygwin/;mirrors.metapeer.com;United States;Washington/>
2017/02/14 12:14:53 io_stream_cygfile: fopen(/etc/setup/installed.db) failed 2 No such file or directory
2017/02/14 12:15:04 io_stream_cygfile: fopen(/etc/setup/setup.rc) failed 2 No such file or directory
2017/02/14 12:15:04 Ending cygwin install
```

How can I solve this error ?

Comment: What error(s) do you get when you use a site you didn't manually enter?

Comment: There are no sites downloaded, all the sites you see there were added manually, the install wizard doesn't get any mirror site

Comment: Feels like your proxy settings are incorrect. I've used setup from open systems and from behind tight corporate firewalls that required extra hoops. You'll need to ensure that you can get to the required sites successfully via setup.exe in your environment.

Comment: I tried my Internet Explorer default proxy settings and it didn't work, while it works on the browser

Answer (score 2):

this happened to me as well. I was behind our workplace proxy and had initially selected the 'use system settings' for the proxy (in the relevant setup page).

This was what's causing grief. I went back to that setup step and manually defined my proxy IP and port. Hit next and I was presented with the prompt to enter proxy auth creds. Did that and next and voila it worked!